# I can't get the value of the variable

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript and there is a question that I can't understand:

Consider the given code:

```
let names = ['ahmed', 'karima', 'hamza','soad'];  
let modifiedNames = names.forEach(name => name+99);
```

The value of modifiedNames here will be?

I am printing the variable in the console but it gives me undefined?!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `foreach` does not return anything. It only iterates over your collection (`names`).

Comment: Use `map` instead of the `forEach`

Comment: What do you expect the result of adding a number to a string to be?

Comment: This may help to understand... `let modifiedNames = names.forEach(name => console.log(name+99));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) which always returns `undefined`.  Use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) if you want to map your array into a new one.

```js
let names = ['ahmed', 'karima', 'hamza','soad'];  
let modifiedNames = names.map(name => name+99);
console.log(modifiedNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [the documentation for `forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> Return value
>
> ```
> undefined.
> ```

Therefore `modifiedNames` will be `undefined`.